# How to kill oracle session when exiting browser with php?

Tags: php, oracle, apache, session

I am having issues with a PHP application. The users are not signing out of the PHP web application and the session on Oracle's side is getting stuck. Is there a script that can be executed when a user exits the webpage to somehow kill the php session as well as the oracle session?

Comment: There is no _reliable_ way of knowing that the user closed the browser

Comment: Sounds to me like your problems are more likely to be found in the way you coded your PHP

Comment: I've not used Oracle, but can you keep a session store with last access time, and then have a cleanup job to delete any login sessions older than x and kill the related oracle session?

Comment: You could set the `IDLE_TIME` parameter for the Oracle user profile that your PHP users are using. If you set it to 30 minutes, db sessions which are idle for more than 30 minutes will be disconnected.

Comment: Perhaps this approach is over-simplified, but I use a [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) listener to make sure the user has saved the data. (of course now I'm worried, since @RiggsFolly says there is no _reliable_ way!). Cross-browser compatibility and UX issues notwithstanding, it may be worth exploring.